# Real examples of how to work-around attr-as-block mode in Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm working with resource [google_compute_subnetwork](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_subnetwork) and have noticed the **[secondary_ip_range](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_subnetwork#secondary_ip_range)** dynamic block doesn't seem to get updated when values are removed.  The doc says this, which may explain why:

> This field uses attr-as-block mode to avoid breaking users during the
> 0.12 upgrade. To explicitly send a list of zero objects you must use the following syntax: example=[]

I have read the [Attributes as Blocks](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/attr-as-blocks) link, but don't understand what I should be doing.  I didn't start working with Terraform until v0.13, so don't have any experience working in v0.11 or v0.12.  With everything else, if a pass a [] to the for_each, the dynamic block is removed.  Is this one different?

Or is this a provider/api limitation and the above message just a red herring?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the documentation uses the placeholder "example" when it's already talking about a specific attribute name, but essentially it's trying to tell you to write the following to declare that you intend to have zero secondary IP ranges:

```
  secondary_ip_range = []
```

If you just write *nothing* (no blocks of type `secondary_ip_range`) then the provider understands that as "ignore whatever secondary IP ranges already exist in the remote API", rather than as "there should be zero secondary IP ranges".

As the documentation implies, this is accommodating a historical design problem in the provider which it must now be backward-compatible with.

Comment: So actually I removed the dynamic block entirely and still got the same behavior.

Comment: It would help if you could share the configuration you've tried as part of your question and then I expect I'll be able to show you a concrete example based on your existing configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually to not use a dynamic block at all and instead write [secondary_ip_range](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_subnetwork#secondary_ip_range) as an attribute inside the resource. I do agree the code mentioning 'example = []' was confusing because I interpreted that as input, and found it made no difference.

There are now two threads showing sample code with the fix:

- https://github.com/aws2gcp/gcp-network-terraform/issues/7
- https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/issues/161